# SQL combine two count outomes

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello any hints on how to achieve the following.

```
select GENDER, count(AGENT_CODE) as Total_Agents from Agents group by Gender
```

Results:

```
GENDER Total_Agents
F      4
M      8
```

This:

```
select count(*) as Total_Customers, Agents.GENDER 
from Agents join Customer 
on Agents.AGENT_CODE = Customer.AGENT_CODE 
group by Agents.GENDER
```

Results:

```
Total_Customers GENDER
11              F
14              M
```

I tried the following:

```
select count(AGENT_CODE) as Count,Gender as Gender from Agents group by Gender
union
select count(*) as Count, Agents.GENDER from Agents join 
Customer on Agents.AGENT_CODE = Customer.AGENT_CODE
group by Agents.GENDER
```

Results:

```
Count Gender 
4     F
11    F 
8     M
14    M
```

EVEN THIS FAILS

```
select count(Agents.AGENT_CODE) as Total_Agents, count(Customer.AGENT_CODE) as 
Total_Customers, Agents.GENDER 
from Agents join Customer on Agents.AGENT_CODE = Customer.AGENT_CODE 
group by Agents.GENDER;

Total_Customers Total_Agents Agents_Gender
       14           14             M
       14           11             F
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT : ALL IN single table like this:

```
Total_Agents Total_Customers Agents_Gender
8             14             M
4             11             F
```

---

TABLE STRUCTURE

- Agents
  [image]
- Customer
  [image]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: like this Total_Agents Total_Customers Agents_Gender
               8             14             M
               4             11             F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must count the distinct `agent_code`s and `cust_code`s:

```
select  
  count(distinct a.agent_code) Total_Agents,
  count(distinct c.cust_code) Total_Customers,
  a.gender
from agents a inner join customer c 
on a.agent_code = c.agent_code
group by a.gender
```

Comment: Firstly Thank you so much for editing. And yes it worked. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select count(Agents.AGENT_CODE) as Total_Agents, count(Customer.AGENT_CODE) as 
Total_Customers, Agents.GENDER 
from Agents join Customer on Agents.AGENT_CODE = Customer.AGENT_CODE 
group by Agents.GENDER;
```

Comment: I tried this but it wont show you the count of Agents. I will display the total counts i.e 11 and 14.

Comment: In that case please provide your table structure and sample data. So that can help you on that

Comment: Yes i have add the table structure. Please suggest if you can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works but can you put this data and the structure into : [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9) so that we can test and see the results and even modify my answer in case of error please.

```
SELECT
  (select count(AGENT_CODE) as Count from Agents group by Gender) as Total_Agents,
  (select count(*) as Count, Agents.GENDER from Agents 
     join Customer on Agents.AGENT_CODE = Customer.AGENT_CODE
      group by Agents.GENDER
  ) as Total_Customers, 
  GENDER
FROM Agents
```

Comment: select  
  count(distinct a.AGENT_CODE) Total_Agents,
  count(distinct c.CUST_CODE) Total_Customers,
  a.GENDER
from Agents a inner join Customer c 
on a.AGENT_CODE = c.AGENT_CODE
group by a.GENDER